# How does stackoverflow website adjust its css to be responsive

Tags: html, css

[image: stackoverflow css adjusting its width even when the applied rule is not set to be responsive]

How is stackoverflow site adjusting for smaller screens when it's header css property is set to width: 1060px;
It is still adjusting for lesser resolution

Comment: What you discover in the chrome developer tools is really confusing. Although it says 100%, it doesn't mean that the width of the page (or header) adapts to the width of the window. Actually this chrome feature zooms out to fit the content on the smaller screen (this might be what a smartphone will do if there wasn't the mobile version). The 100% just means that the set dimensions scale to this percentage. Try using the FF dev tools for a better understanding or just decrease the width of your chrome window.

Comment: It's not responsive, it's adaptive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't. There is a separate mobile version with a fluid layout, for the probable reason that this version [is different enough](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210516) from the desktop version to be separated.

Whether the site should have a fluid or fixed-width layout [has been discussed on meta before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5070/can-so-have-a-fluid-vs-fixed-width-layout).